# How do you get the avatar of any tumblr post as an image via html?

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

Okay I am using tumblr themes, and I really need a method of getting the avatar of the user who posted a post. I know you can do this with question posts, but I need it for *every* post.

I have tried something like what is below, but I can't find a solution.

```
<img class="iconphotos" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_{BlogIdentifier}_128.pnj"/>
```

and

```
<img class="iconphotos" src="https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{BlogIdentifier}/avatar/128"/>
```

None of the above attempts worked, and I have gone through the [tumblr documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) for themes to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a typo in the first one, you put .pnj instead of .png

As for the second one, use `{blog-identifier}` instead of `{BlogIdentifier}`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, but that really didn't change anything the issue still stands.

Comment: What about {PostAuthorPortraitURL-128}?

Comment: Yeah I've tried this as well, but it always manages to give my avatar instead of their avatar